# Is there a way to check if a url exists without sending a request directly?

Tags: javascript, url, svg, axios, request

I get the svg url using Google Autodraw API. The problem is that some of these urls(The svg url I processed using the picture name obtained from the API) jaggedly don't exist.

I only need to filter out the list of valid urls. For this, I used the method of sending a axios request. However, this method is accompanied by time lag problem when fetching list of urls each time.

Is there any other way to solve this problem? I don't have my server..just client-side.

Here is the code I wrote.

```js
  const validateSuggestions = async (suggestions) => {
    const validSuggestions = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < suggestions.length; i++) {
      const suggestion = suggestions[i];

      try {
        await axios(suggestion.url);

        validSuggestions.push(suggestion);
      } catch (error) {
        continue;
      }
    }

    return validSuggestions;
  };
```

Comment: In order to verify if a request to a URL will give you a successful response, you do need to make a request to the URL. You cannot really guess whether a URL will give you an error or not without trying it. You could could send the requests *in parallel* instead of *in sequence, though. You can further try a HEAD request instead of a full GET. But still involves making requests.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for answer. I used "await.head". But "await.all" seems to catch the error in "catch" immediately when one request fails. I need to send another request even if one request fails. Is there no other way to do this in parallel?

Comment: @VLAZ

I solved the problem using "Promise.allSettled". "axios.all" is deprecated so I should use "Promise.all" instead. I used "Promise.allSettled" because I have to send another request even if one request fails. Thanks for your help!